# Why am I getting 403 error from Google Storage for this Shopify response using Indy

Tags: delphi, google-cloud-storage, indy, shopify-api

I have an authenticated url from shopify, where the results from a bulk operation are stored. I am getting a 403 error from indy trying to GET this data. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. The URL is fine / I have permission, as you can see by pasting the url to browser which presents the jsonl response.

[Authenticated URL](https://storage.googleapis.com/shopify-tiers-assets-prod-us-east1/l9qx25bn40srq20ihwremefeaa81?GoogleAccessId=assets-us-prod%40shopify-tiers.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1680018264&Signature=g8tFS3W%2FR2O6GfU74XCVttX954dcdycDPvoHklRnuUHAjpNwyxkwNsnK40r6%2FaxRAWL3X8XdWsBmBVLV4o94YiJTwg9yG7RQLIgJyytr3Rmx3ei1nPClRFQuE1Opm%2Fx1nhQXStTGs10BqQ98rqWgNhdG%2BSMqA2KB1QdYA6e1qzfDd%2F1VjSuI21ntQJswgVy0M5cY%2FPKo8%2FR%2F1U8K95V%2FjpXX12t9pgKpdU1axi0N0EpCzcFsgBMna2%2B0pT9qzS9ALV%2FzsE2QcFpcRyCIo1g7jX6apX1ZDlINYSWPzhqhQCZXV4bM0BmCIadIWOkjMT1YiMZecIoctTtzKgytsCXjdA%3D%3D)

Code:

```
uses IdHTTP, IdSSLOpenSSL;

  procedure TfrmMain.btnDownloadFromGoogleClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      FileStream         : TFileStream;
      FURL, FResponseFile: string;
      SSL                : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
      Api                : Tidhttp;
    begin
      FURL          := 'https://storage.googleapis.com/shopify-tiers-assets-prod-us-east1/l9qx25bn40srq20ihwremefeaa81?GoogleAccessId=assets-us-prod%40shopify-tiers.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1680018264&Signature=g8tFS3W%2FR2O6GfU74XCVttX954dcdycDPvoHklRnuUHAjpNwyxkwNsnK40r6%2FaxRAWL3X8XdWsBmBVLV4o94Y' +
'iJTwg9yG7RQLIgJyytr3Rmx3ei1nPClRFQuE1Opm%2Fx1nhQXStTGs10BqQ98rqWgNhdG%2BSMqA2KB1QdYA6e1qzfDd%2F1VjSuI21ntQJswgVy0M5cY%2FPKo8%2FR%2F1U8K95V%2FjpXX12t9pgKpdU1axi0N0EpCzcFsgBMna2%2B0pT9qzS9ALV%2FzsE2QcFpcRyCIo1g7jX6apX1ZDlINYSWPzhqhQCZXV4bM0BmCIadIWOkjMT1YiMZecIoctTtzKgytsCXjdA%3D%3D';
      FResponseFile := 'bulkresponsegraphql.jsonl';
      FileStream    := TFileStream.create(FResponseFile, fmCreate);
      try
        Api := Tidhttp.create();
        try
          SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.create(Api);
          try
            SSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];

            Api.Request.Clear;
            Api.IOHandler       := SSL;
            Api.HandleRedirects := True;

            try

              { same result with/out headers
Api.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('GoogleAccessId', 'assets-us-prod%40shopify-tiers.iam.gserviceaccount.com');
              Api.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Signature', 'g8tFS3W%2FR2O6GfU74XCVttX954dcdycDPvoHklRnuUHAjpNwyxkwNsnK40r6%2FaxRAWL3X8XdWsBmBVLV4o94YiJTwg9yG7RQLIgJyytr3Rmx3ei1nPClRFQuE1Opm%2Fx1nhQXStTGs10BqQ98rqWgNhdG%2BSMqA2K' +
                  'B1QdYA6e1qzfDd%2F1VjSuI21ntQJswgVy0M5cY%2FPKo8%2FR%2F1U8K95V%2FjpXX12t9pgKpdU1axi0N0EpCzcFsgBMna2%2B0pT9qzS9ALV%2FzsE2QcFpcRyCIo1g7jX6apX1ZDlINYSWPzhqhQCZXV4bM0BmCIadIWOkjMT1YiMZecIoctTtzKgytsCXjdA%3D%3D');
              Api.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Expires', '1680018264');
}
              Api.Get(FURL, FileStream);

            except
              on e: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
                Memo1.Lines.add('HTTP status code: ' + inttostr(e.ErrorCode) + slinebreak + 'Error message: ' + e.Message + ', ' + e.ErrorMessage);
              on e: exception do
                Memo1.Lines.add(e.Message);
            end;
          finally
            SSL.free;
          end;

        finally
          Api.free;
        end;
      finally
        FileStream.free;
      end;

    end;
```

Response:

```
HTTP status code: 403
Error message: HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden, <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message><StringToSign>GET


1680018264
/www.google.com/shopify-tiers-assets-prod-us-east1/l9qx25bn40srq20ihwremefeaa81</StringToSign></Error>
HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
```

Thank you

Comment: If you access the URL in the browser you say it works, but it isn't passing the `CustomHeaders` you are providing.  They're query arguments on the URL.  Check the URL you are actually providing is the same as the browser, and pass the same thing - you won't need custom headers if the browser isn't using them.  Developer Tools in the browser can show you the request and response with headers.

Comment: Thanks @RobLambden. The `FURL` I'm passing, from `mmInputs.Lines.Text`, is the exact same text as in the url in the post. ie it has the query arguments. I've tried with and without the custom headers - same result.  I actually forgot I'd left them in this post. I only tried them because when using postman it auto-added them, so thought I'd try. I have tried looking through the browser Dev Tools and couldn't see anything. The URL should be accessible to you/anyone.

Comment: Some web servers are sensitive to a request's `User-Agent` header, reacting differently based on what kind of client is making the request. Unfortunately, some web servers have a bad habit of flat out rejecting requests from Indy's default `User-Agent`, so I would suggest changing the `TIdHTTP.Request.UserAgent` to mimic an actual web browser and see if that makes any difference in your situation. Although I did try using my web browser's dev tools to modify a request to use Indy's default `User-Agent` and it didn't seem to matter. But it's worth trying just to eliminate it as a factor.

Comment: Oh, wait, this is a pre-signed URL. Do you know which header values were used to sign it in the first place? Those same headers need to appear in the request so the signature can be validated.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau - a good suggestion (and one I had to implement exactly as you suggest to get access to Amazon web page using your indy), but unfortunately it hasn't helped here. I tried `MSIE 6.0` and `Request.UserAgent := Format('Mozilla/%d.0 (Windows NT %d.%d; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/%d.%d.%d', [RandomRange(3, 5), RandomRange(3, 5), Random(2), RandomRange(3, 5), Random(5), Random(5)]);

Comment: @RemyLebeau the code I have posted now is a complete working (or not...) example. The URL has the query parameters, I don't know anything more - shopify only provide the URL. No headers (should?) be needed, because if you paste the URL to browser, it works.

Comment: @Joao You are logging only the HTTP response code, but what does the complete HTTP response look like? Does it carry any payload data that explains WHY the request was rejected?

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you ... I forgot about `e.ErrorMessage` I thought I was getting the full response from `e.Message`. So, the full response tells me `<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message><StringToSign>GET


1680018264
/www.google.com/shopify-tiers-assets-prod-us-east1/l9qx25bn40srq20ihwremefeaa81</StringToSign>`. So, now I need to see why this is failing when I send the URL through indy, but not when it's opened in browser.

Comment: @Joao You can use an `Intercept` component to log the full request that `TIdHTTP` is actually sending, and then compare that to the request that your browser is sending. But off-hand, other than `User-Agent` I don't really see any other headers that should be relevant to this issue. But, without knowing which headers are being used to sign the URL, and seeing documentation telling you which headers to send, it is impossible to answer this question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , thanks I will check intercept also. But, the URL is already signed, I didn't generate the signature, and there is no documentation relevant (https://shopify.dev/docs/api/usage/bulk-operations/queries#download-result-data). The signature is already provided by shopify and included. From your guidance to check e.errorMessage, I can see that it says the signature is not correct. Given that if I post this exact URL 1) to browser, it works (so the signature is correct), or 2) to TIdhttp.get, it fails. So I guess it is something to do with some encoding when I am sending through indy?

Comment: @Joao "*the URL is already signed, I didn't generate the signature*" - No, but certain header values are included in the hash that creates the signature, and you have to send matching headers in subsequent requests, which the server will use to check the signature is valid. For example, `Content-Type` may be one such signed header, so if a request has a different `Content-Type` then what was signed then the validated signature won't match the original signature.